# ES6 import syntax imports whole file instead of function only

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of JS files with quite a few functions. In one of the files, I have a function written that I wish to export and use in another file. Here is the function:

```
export default function updateMinimumAmountNotice(subtotal) {
    let parsedSubtotal = parseFloat(subtotal);
    let minimumOrderAmount = parseFloat(minimum_order_amount);
    if (parsedSubtotal < minimumOrderAmount) {
        minimumOrderNotice.find('#checkout-amount').text((minimumOrderAmount - parsedSubtotal).toFixed(2));
    } else if (parsedSubtotal >= minimumOrderAmount) {
        minimumOrderNotice.hide();
    }
}
```

In my other file, I am importing it like so:

`import updateMinimumAmountNotice from './single-product';`

When I import the function `updateMinimumAmountNotice`, I get errors on the page that are from non-imported functions in the same file of the function that I am importing. None of those functions are exported and the file is not loaded on the page. Most of the JS files are page-specific and only load on the page they have logic for.

If it matters, I am using Webpack as a build tool with BrowserSync.

So, is this normal behavior for importing/exporting modules, or is there something else going on?

Comment: and if you remove `import updateMinimumAmountNotice from './single-product';` do the errors disappear?

Comment: If they’re not the type of error that only occurs after running the function – syntax errors, for example – then yes, it’s normal.

Comment: @AndreiCACIO Yes, they do. I ended up pull that one function into it's own file and the errors go away. In that single file, I created a function that outputted some text to the console. I did not export that function, however, it still outputted to the console.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure I follow what you are saying. The reason I noticed this was happening was because the one file was looking for elements that didn't exist on the page and was causing errors. Just FYI.

Comment: @dericcain: If you don’t call a function somewhere, it won’t run. Sounds like functions are running when you don’t expect them to, but that’s not because of the module system.

Comment: @Ryan So, if I have File A and Module A (inside File A) and I export Module A. Then in File B, I import Module A. Does it import all functions in File A as well? I have a function in File A that is not exported that is being called in File B when I import Module A to File B. Doesn't seem right to me but maybe it is.

Comment: @dericcain: What’s calling the function? There’s not much sense in making a distinction between imported and non-imported, because importing a function doesn’t have side-effects.

Comment: @Ryan The function is called in File B and pertains, in no way, to File A or Module A.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139300/discussion-between-ryan-and-dericcain).