# ES6 import only what I ask for, not the entire file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

This question might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076402/es6-import-syntax-imports-whole-file-instead-of-function-only), however my setup and context are different.

**Setup**:

- I use rollup, rollup-plugin-terser, rollup-plugin-buble, rollup-plugin-json (and other cleanup and stuff).
- I'm making sub-versions of the same object.

The *script-full.js* has it all.

```js
// the full version script-full.js
import myClass from './myClass.js'
import myObject from './myObject.js'
import otherFunction from './functions.js'

const props1 = ['p1','p2'...] // a very long array

export function doSomeStuff(prop){
  // do some magic with myObject
  myObject[prop] = function(prop){
    // nothing important or related to the specifics of this file
    otherFunction(prop)
  }
}

export const myOps1 = {
  props: props1,
  fn: doSomeStuff
}

export default new myClass(myOps1)
```

The *script-base.js* has it's own *props*.

```js
// the base version script-base.js
import myClass from './myClass.js'
import {doSomeStuff} from './script-full.js'

const props2 = ['p1','p2'] // a short array

export const myOps2 = {
  props: props2,
  fn: doSomeStuff
}

export default new myClass(myOps2)
```

Now rollup takes care of the indexes for me:

*index-full.js*

```js
export script1 from './script-full.js'
```

*index-base.js*

```js
export script2 from './script-base.js'
```

**Problem**

Before the *script-base.js*, rollup will also include the entire file from *script-full.js* into the compiled file.

**Questions**:

- Is there any way to prevent this unwanted inclusion? I want that base version to be lighter.
- I'm thinking probably I should do the base version first and extend with full version, is that a better way? Is that the only way?

**Thank you**

Comment: I cannot see what is `doSomeStuff` doing. But is my believe that if `doSomeStuff` logic depends on any other elements of the *script-full.js* file-scope, these elements will also be included during rollup tree-shaking.

Comment: Edited, check `doSomeStuff()`